# How to select a deafult choice with radio buttons - in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to select a default value on a radio. I use v0.13.3, which honors `checked={value===selected_value}` by setting `checked` attribute if the expression evaluates to true.

In the generated HTML (formatted by me), the matched radio button is `checked`ed, but I am unable to select any other button.

Why is this happening? What is the correct way to set a checked option?

```
  radio: function(value, selected_value, name, callback) {
    console.log("radio");
    console.log(value===selected_value);
    return(<label>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value={value} checked={value===selected_value}/>{name}
    </label>)
  },

  render: function() {
    selected_value = "com";
    return (
      <div>
        Options:
        <br/>
        {this.radio("cha", selected_value, "CM", null)}
        <br/>
        {this.radio("lea", selected_value, "L D", null)}
        <br/>
        {this.radio("com", selected_value, "Com", null)}
      </div>
    )
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div data-reactid=".0"><span data-reactid=".0.0">Options:</span><br data-reactid=".0.1"><label data-reactid=".0.2">

<input name="type" value="cha" data-reactid=".0.2.0" type="radio"><span data-reactid=".0.2.1">CM</span></label><br data-reactid=".0.3"><label data-reactid=".0.4">

<input name="type" value="l" data-reactid=".0.4.0" type="radio"><span data-reactid=".0.4.1">L D</span></label><br data-reactid=".0.5"><label data-reactid=".0.6">

<input name="type" value="com" checked="" data-reactid=".0.6.0" type="radio"><span data-reactid=".0.6.1">Com</span></label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By manually setting the `checked` prop, you are creating [Controlled Components](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), which will not respond to user input unless you explicitly define an `onChange` event handler to tell the components what to do when a user interacts with it.

I believe what you are looking for is the `defaultChecked` prop.  Setting this to `true` or `false` will instead create Uncontrolled Components, which will respond to user input normally, while still giving you the behavior you are looking for.